# jQuery syntax - when to use $ (dollar) vs jQuery

Tags: jquery, syntax

What's difference between this two?

```
$('#SPANID').html("Some Text");

jQuery('#SPANID').html("Some Text");
```

Is it something prototype vs jQuery?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They both do the same thing. Most Libraries use $ as a shorter way to access functions within the libraries.

jQuery has many ways of accessing its library:

```
window.jQuery('#SPANID').html("Some Text");

window.$('#SPANID').html("Some Text");

jQuery('#SPANID').html("Some Text");

$('#SPANID').html("Some Text");
```

jQuery or window.jQuery can be used instead of $ if you were using more than one library.

JQuery has a function called [jQuery.noConflict();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which relinquishs jQuery's control of the $ variable making $ not work with jQuery.

This would be good for using more than one library that use $.

So you when you use jQuery you would do `jQuery('#message').addClassName('read');` and `$('#message').addClassName('read');` when using Prototype.

(This next bit is a little off topic but will help if you want to use $ with multiple libraries)

Although there is a way to use $ on different libraries at the same time, using anonymous functions. like so:

```
(function($){


})(jQuery);


(function($){


})(Prototype);
```

Each of the functions passes the library object, so jQuery and Prototype, as the variable $ allowing use to use it with many libraries. If you contain your code for each library within each one it will work.

For example:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

         $('#message').addClass('read');

    });

})(jQuery);


(function($){
     document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {

         $('message').addClassName('read');
         //Or
         $$('#message').addClassName('read');

     });

})(Prototype);
```

Comment: +1 this is a good thorough answer if a little off topic :)

Comment: @Tomgrohl, thanks for your input. It really simple to understand now.

Comment: @Patricia True. I learnt it the other day and thought it worth mentioning :)

Comment: Would've been nice if you mentioned jQuery.noConflict() too.

Comment: @Daniel Good point I'll add that in.

Comment: @Tomgrohl - Prototype would actually be  `$('message').addClassName('read');` (hash removed from $ function)

Comment: @seengee That was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 17):

if you are using more then one javascript library there can be conflicts if you just use the **$**.   using **jQuery** will avoid those.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Furthermore, jQuery has a noConflict() method which can be called to relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable, allowing it to play nicely in the sandbox alongside other frameworks.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: This is only the correct answer if you also use .noConflict.

Comment: What do you mean by "using more than one javascript library"?  Is that means using more than javascript plug-in?  Could you please give me an example where it can be conflicts to have a good understanding of basics?

Comment: @EndangeredMassa - But, but... @twerq said it was the correct answer. I'm so confused... ;)

Comment: by more then one library i mean: jquery, prototype, ext, yui.

Answer (score 6):

It's an alias for the same thing. If you want to use jQuery on the same page as other libraries that use the `$` symbol, you can use jQuery with the [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) option. This will allow you to use `$` for the other library and `jQuery` for the jQuery library.

Answer (score 4):

No difference actually, except for the fact that `jQuery('SPANID')` should actually be `jQuery('#SPANID')`

$ is just a shorthand for jQuery

EDIT: I understand that the real difference between $ and jQuery is in the possibile namespace collision with other libraries. Other than that, they work the same way.

Comment: No difference? You sure about that?

Comment: there was a typeo. it should be jQuery('#SPANID')

Comment: `$` is an alias of `jQuery`, so it behaves exactly the same... except`$` has a higher risk of namespace collisions (with other js libraries).

Answer (score 1):

Using the explicit "jquery" would avoid a clash if you happened to also reference another library which used "$"

Answer (score 0):

The difference is this: `$` is often used by other libraries or JavaScript constructs, so it could be overwritten and may not do what you expect. `jQuery` always refers to the jQuery library, so it will do what you expect.

In environments where you cannot guarantee that `$` will not be overwritten by something else, using `jQuery` or [`jQuery.noConflict( )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) is safer than `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery when you've got another library that's already defined `$`.  Use `$` as the convenient shorthand it is when you don't (or inside of function scopes where you don't have to worry about it. :)

Although personally, I think `jq` would make a nice shorthand (same number of keystrokes as `$`, probably a little less common).

Answer (score 0):

It's not just short hand but it is made for other JavaScript libraries that might be using the $ character and to avoid confusion or conflict then using the jquery keyword is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

More details are here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

The $ is an alias for jQuery which (jQuery) is a Javascript library.
Plug-ins are usage of the library in a specific fashion which create specific use of the library and extend its functionality.

Some examples of use:

"Regular" jQuery code:

```
   $(function(){ 
      // my jquery code here
    });
```

NOTE: this is an EVENT management which is to say, it executes on the DOM ready event.

Plug-in code:

```
(function($){ 
   //theplugin code here 
})( jQuery );
```

This allows the use of the $ inside without confusion because it says "assign jQuery to the $ passed in the function($)

---

```
$(function(){ 
  //stuff here such as jQuery code
});
```

as in

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#mybutton").click(function() {
     alert("hi");)
  )};
});
```

Is the same as:

```
(function($) { 
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
       alert("hi");
    )};
  }) 
})(jQuery)
```

but perhaps not as good as (without the binding (jQuery) at the end), which only comes into play if you use other libraries that use the $.

---

$ is just a character, thus you can have variables such as:

myvariable = 0;
$myvariable = 0;
my$variable = 0;

Nothing special here, just using another character.

I just so happens that a common use of $ is $ = jQuery;  Other libraries use this character as a common shorthand (alias sort of) as well, thus the noconflict and the use of the full name (jQuery).