# jquery.js conflicts with prototype.js

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I'm using prototype.js for light box window and jquery.validate.js using for form validation in same window but both the scripts are getting conflicts

i used noconflict function but light box only working form validation is not working

**light box script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/prototype.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/effects.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/window.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/window_effects.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/debug.js"> </script>
```

**validation sctipt**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling validation, and `.noConflict()`?

Comment: Also as a side note, there's a lightbox plugin for jQuery...so do you even need to use both libraries?

Answer (score 3):

If you call `jQuery.noConflict();` it would not associate $ with jQuery.

Then you would just use jquery functions as `JQuery(element).html()` and Prototype with $.

As Nick suggested, there's a lightbox jQuery plugin, which can be found [here](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

If you really need to use both, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291680/jquery-syntax-when-to-use-vs-jquery/3291916#3291916) has some information that might help you.

But it might be best to stick with one library to avoid the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/prototype.js"></script>-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lightbox.js"></script>-->       
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/videobox.js"></script>    
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>-->    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.boxgrid.caption').each(function () {
            jQuery(this).mouseenter (function() {
                jQuery(this).find(".cover").animate({top:'50px'}, {queue:false, duration:160});
            });     
            jQuery(this).mouseleave (function() {
                jQuery(this).find(".cover").animate({top:'150px'}, {queue:false, duration:160});
            });     
        });
        jQuery("a.external").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put `<script src="jquery.js">` (and all the other jQuery stuff) first, then embed the prototype scripts, Prototype will overwrite anything that jQuery defines that conflicts with Prototype (ie. `$` will belong to Prototype). Then, Lightbox can use Prototype via the `$` variable and you can use `jQuery(...)` instead of `$(...)` for jQuery stuff.

[Details from jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Including_jQuery_before_Other_Libraries)