# In jQuery some time '$' making trouble?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery some time '$' making trouble, what is the basic reason ? Answer in detail.

Thanks in Advance

```
jQuery(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291680/jquery-syntax-when-to-use-dollar-vs-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because other library also use `$` so there will be conflict use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

or like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have another library which also makes use of `$`.

In which case you can make use of [`jQuery.noConflict.()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(function () {
   j("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be conflict with other plugins like prototype for example that also uses the $ sign

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason is that the `$` variable is also used by others javascript framework like Prototypejs and Mootools.

So if you want to use both jQuery and Mootools for instance, you should avoid the use of `$`.