# jQuery not working for event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery but I know a couple of things. However when I try to do events it never seems to work.
HTML code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=password]").focus(function() {
    $("#password_information").show();
  }).blur(function() {
    $("password_information").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <span><input id = "username" name = "username" type = "text"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="pswd">Password:</label>
      <span><input id = "pswd" type = "password" name = "pswd"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="submit">Register</button>
  </ul>
</form>
<div id="password_information">
  <h4> Password must meet the following requirements:</h4>
  <ul>
    <li id="letter" class="invalid">At Least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
    <li id="captial" class="invalid">At Least <strong>one captial</strong></li>
    <li id="number" class="invalid">At Least <strong>one number</strong></li>
    <li id="length" class="invalid">At Least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is in an external script within in the same location as the html file.

For some reason it doesn't work, could you explain why or help me fix that?

Comment: What's your console log say? Are you sure the jQuery library is being loaded?

Comment: Did you link every JS file correctly to your HTML ? JQuery first then your file?

Comment: "Why does this code not work" is off topic on StachOverflow. Please elaborate on what errors you're experiencing, what debug steps you have taken.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo... `$("password_information")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's focus() and focusout() method to achieve this.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input[type=password]").focus(function(){
    jQuery("#password_information").show();
  });
  jQuery("input[type=password]").focusout(function(){
    jQuery("#password_information").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#password_information{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for = "username">Username:</label>
      <span><input id = "username" name = "username" type = "text"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for = "pswd">Password:</label>
      <span><input id = "pswd" type = "password" name = "pswd"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type = "submit">Register</button>
  </ul>
</form>
<div id = "password_information">
  <h4> Password must meet the following requirements:</h4>
  <ul>
    <li id = "letter" class = "invalid">At Least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
    <li id = "captial" class = "invalid">At Least <strong>one captial</strong></li>
    <li id = "number" class = "invalid">At Least <strong>one number</strong></li>
    <li id = "length" class = "invalid">At Least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, nothing happens. Plus why are you replacing the $ for "JQuery" because i have done this and tried both $ and jQuery and still nothing happened

Comment: Please try to run the code snippet above and click on the password field..

Comment: so why does mine not work . Could it be something to do with how I'm referencing my js file?

Comment: 'Why are you replacing the $ for jQuery?'
My answer is in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291680/jquery-syntax-when-to-use-dollar-vs-jquery

Double check your code and make sure that you have imported the jQuery script in your header. Or check your browser's console log for any errors.

Comment: And make sure that you've hidden your password_information div so that 'show()' and 'hide()' method will work.

Answer (score 0):

found the problem, it's the hash(for id selecting):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=password]").focus(function() {
    $("#password_information").show();
  }).focusout(function() { //blur and focusout both works fine
    $("#password_information").hide(); //here you forgot it 
  });
});
```